# How do I run an application with cyrillic language in wine?

Tags: ubuntu, wine, cyrillic

Iam trying to launch a Russian application with wine, but I cant read the text since it is in cyrillic.

I have tried LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 wine program.exe but the program can not be executed via the terminal. I have to manually start it from its location.

Any ideas how to install the cyrillic in the whole wine emulator? Or how to run the application with cyrillic?

Comment: LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 wine "/home/username/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/filename/filename.exe"
Solved it.